# Count() a specfic attribute within a list c#

Tags: c#

```
if (gardenvlist.Count() == getava.Count())
{

}
else if(oceanvlist.Count() == getava.Count())
{

}
else if (cityvlist.Count() == getava.Count())
{

}
```

`gardenvlist` is a list of dates that are available for a period with a specific room named garden.

`getava` is a list of dates that are available for a period with multiple roomnames: garden, ocean, city.

I would like to select the count of only garden (or some other specific name) in `getava` and then compare with the list.

How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps English is not your first language, can you please edit your question because right now I do not understand your question.

Comment: Instead of describing what the lists represent, please show us the code that creates them or at least the type of each list.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more code? It'd be a lot easier to help if we knew what the base type of your list was

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can pass in a lambda expression to `Count()` to selectively count items based on properties then compare that to whatever you'd like. Something like this:

`if (gardenvlist.Count()== getava.Count(x => x.Name == "GardenName"))`

Note you will need to add the following using statement:
`using System.Linq`

Answer (score 2):

There is another overload of `Count()` that takes a lambda expression as a parameter where you can filter elements to count from the source collection.

Say you have a list of strings like this:

```
var list = new List<string>() {
   "a",
   "b",
   "c",
   "aa",
   "bbb"
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var countSingles = list.Count(str => str.Length == 1);
```

This will count the elements of the list with length 1, so here it would return `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload which takes a predicate. Here is the signature:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

Imaging you have this:

```
public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you put them into a list:

```
var rooms = new List<Room>()
{
    new Room { Name = "Living" },
    new Room { Name = "Kitchen" }
};
```

You want to know how many rooms have the name "Living":

```
int count = rooms.Count(x => x.Name == "Living");
```